# Mixed Modelling - Different Results between lme and lmer functions

Tags: r, lme4, mixed-models, nlme

I am currently working through Andy Field's book, Discovering Statistics Using R. Chapter 14 is on Mixed Modelling and he uses the `lme` function from the `nlme` package.

The model he creates, using speed dating data, is such:

```
speedDateModel <- lme(dateRating ~ looks + personality +
                 gender + looks:gender + personality:gender + 
                 looks:personality,
    random = ~1|participant/looks/personality)
```

I tried to recreate a similar model using the `lmer` function from the `lme4` package; however, my results are different. I thought I had the proper syntax, but maybe not?

```
speedDateModel.2 <- lmer(dateRating ~ looks + personality + gender + 
              looks:gender + personality:gender + 
              (1|participant) + (1|looks) + (1|personality), 
              data = speedData, REML = FALSE)
```

Also, when I run the coefficients of these models I notice that it only produces random intercepts for each participant. I was trying to then create a model that produces both random intercepts and slopes. I can't seem to get the syntax correct for either function to do this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

The only difference between the `lme` and the corresponding `lmer` formula should be that the random and fixed components are aggregated into a single formula:

```
dateRating ~ looks + personality +
             gender + looks:gender + personality:gender + 
             looks:personality+ (1|participant/looks/personality)
```

using `(1|participant) + (1|looks) + (1|personality)` is only equivalent if `looks` and `personality` have unique values at each nested level.

It's not clear what continuous variable you want to define your slopes: if you have a continuous variable `x` and groups `g`, then `(x|g)` or equivalently `(1+x|g)` will give you a random-slopes model (`x` should also be included in the fixed-effects part of the model, i.e. the full formula should be `y~x+(x|g)` ...)

**update**: I got the data, or rather a script file that allows one to reconstruct the data, from [here](http://studysites.sagepub.com/dsur/study/DSUR%20R%20Script%20Files/Chapter%2014%20DSUR%20GLM5.R). Field makes a common mistake in his book, which I have made several times in the past: since there is only a single observation in the data set for each participant/looks/personality combination, the three-way interaction has one level per observation.  In a linear mixed model, this means the variance at the lowest level of nesting will be confounded with the residual variance.

You can see this in two ways:

- `lme` *appears* to fit the model just fine, but if you try to calculate confidence intervals via `intervals()`, you get

```
 intervals(speedDateModel)
 ## Error in intervals.lme(speedDateModel) : 
 ##   cannot get confidence intervals on var-cov components: 
 ##   Non-positive definite approximate variance-covariance
```

- If you try this with `lmer` you get:

```
## Error: number of levels of each grouping factor
##   must be < number of observations
```

In both cases, this is a clue that something's wrong. (You *can* overcome this in `lmer` if you really want to: see `?lmerControl`.)

If we leave out the lowest grouping level, everything works fine:

```
sd2 <- lmer(dateRating ~ looks + personality +
                 gender + looks:gender + personality:gender + 
                 looks:personality+
                     (1|participant/looks),
            data=speedData)
```

Compare `lmer` and `lme` fixed effects:

```
all.equal(fixef(sd2),fixef(speedDateModel)) ## TRUE
```

The starling example [here](https://www.nceas.ucsb.edu/system/files/mixedlab.pdf) gives another example and further explanation of this issue.

Comment: Thank you, Ben. In my first model example using the lme() function it produces the correct result. Would you be able to help me understand how to re-write that example with the lmer() function as I can't seem to wrap my head around how to make it work without getting a bunch of errors.

Comment: if I'm going to help you more I need a reproducible example. I poked at the book a little bit on Google Books, but I can't figure out where the `speedData` data set comes from  (also, you should always use the `data=` argument to explicitly specify the data frame for analysis ...)

Comment: Hello, Ben, sorry for not getting back to this yet. Things got really busy. Will try and update with more info later this week if possible. Appreciate it.